# filter unique element from 2 array of objects based on id

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 array like following,How to filter all the unique objects i.e. { cuisine_id: 3, id: 33 } from the selected array of objects?

```
const cuisines = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' }
  
];
const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 1, id: 11},
  { cuisine_id: 2, id: 22},
  { cuisine_id: 3, id: 33 },
];

 expected output:

[{ cuisine_id: 3, id: 33 }]
```

Comment: Please show your attempt. StackOverflow is not a platform that ask to help you writing the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like the following way:

```js
const cuisines = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' }
];

const selected = [
  { cuisine_id: 1, id: 11 },
  { cuisine_id: 2, id: 22 },
  { cuisine_id: 3, id: 33 },
];

const output = selected.filter(item => !cuisines.some(cuisine => cuisine.id === item.cuisine_id));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Oh! I was missing '!' operator and kept getting matching values but not unique. thank you so much for the answer.